# Loop through all panels in form

Tags: vb.net, loops, panel

I want to loop through all panels in my form and set the visible property.
Could You tell me where all panels are stored?

```
Public Function ShowHide(PanelName As String)
    For Each sth As Panel In Form.Panels
        If sth.Name <> PanelName Then
            sth.visible = False
        Else
            sth.visible = True
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub ShowHide(PanelName As String)
    For Each sth As Control In Me.controls
        If TypeOf sth Is Panel Then
            If sth.Name <> PanelName Then
                sth.Visible = False
            Else
                sth.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`OfType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2) Method to only loop through the controls of a specific type:

```
Public Sub ShowHide(PanelName As String)
    For Each sth As Panel In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
        If sth.Name = PanelName Then
            sth.Visible = True
        Else
            sth.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Or if you want to do it in one-line:

```
Public Sub ShowHide(PanelName As String)
    Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel).ToList().ForEach(Sub(p) p.Visible = (p.Name = PanelName))
End Sub
```